# SwiftUI button taps reset SpriteKit animations - is this a bug?

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit

I wanted to have an animated background in my SwiftUI app. I achieved this by using a SpriteKit GameScene as my background, and using SKActions to gradually fade in and out different images.

However, I noticed that when I tap any of the buttons in my SwiftUI app, it completely resets the animation.

Is this a bug? Does anyone know a way around this?

Here is a simplified version of my SwiftUI ContentView.swift:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = GameScene()
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 1125, height: 2436)
        scene.scaleMode = .fill
        return scene
    }

    var body: some View {
        SpriteView(scene: scene)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
            .ignoresSafeArea()

    }

}
```

Here is the code I used to animate my background:

```
    // Animations
let fadeOutAnimation: SKAction = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 5)
let fadeInAnimation: SKAction = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 5)
let wait5Animation: SKAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 5)
let wait10Animation:SKAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10)
let wait20Animation:SKAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 20)

 // Repeating Background Actions
    let firstRepeatingSequence = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([fadeOutAnimation, wait20Animation, fadeInAnimation]))
    let secondRepeatingSequence = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([fadeOutAnimation, wait10Animation, fadeInAnimation, wait10Animation]))
    let thirdRepeatingSequence = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([fadeOutAnimation, fadeInAnimation, wait20Animation]))
    
    //Access bg sprites
    let bg1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "blue1")
    bg1.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    let bg2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "red1")
    bg2.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    let bg3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "green1")
    bg3.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    self.addChild(bg1)
    self.addChild(bg2)
    self.addChild(bg3)
      
    // Run Background forever
    bg3.run(firstRepeatingSequence)
    bg2.run(SKAction.sequence([wait5Animation, secondRepeatingSequence]))
    bg1.run(SKAction.sequence([wait10Animation, thirdRepeatingSequence]))
```

Comment: Is the whole SpriteKit scene being reset every time the view body updates?

Comment: Yes, I think that is what is happening.  It's weird - the buttons have nothing to do with the SpriteKit scene. The app is basically a calculator with a pretty background. The buttons are not tied into the SpriteKit scene in any way.

Comment: A minimal example would be helpful to debug this, such as a really basic scene with just a square that might rotate or change opacity. If I can just paste it in to debug it, I will try fix the problem.

Comment: Need to see the SwiftUI part.  Likely you're making a new scene whenever the interface state is changing.

Comment: Thank you for offering to help, @George_E. I edited the code to add the SwiftUI code I am using to embed the spriteKit code into my SwiftUI contentView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's redrawing the view, and when it does that, it's re-initializing your scene. Make your scene a @State variable and initialize it in an init method.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var scene = GameScene()

    init() {
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 1125, height: 2436)
        scene.scaleMode = .fill
    }

    var body: some View {
        SpriteView(scene: scene)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
            .ignoresSafeArea()

    }

}
```